# how to fixing Html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

[Pie charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSJXB.png)

[Column/line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs9iO.png)

These circles when i capture them by canvas gives me the left image
also in the chart image..
any idea to take the shape as it is

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var element = $("#cont"); // global variable
    var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             },
             width:1500,
             height:1500
         });
    });

    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the JS code you are currently using.

Comment: @nnnnnn updated